# Творительный падеж множественного числа слова "*****" (падшая женщина)

Tags: склонение, обсценная-лексика

Очень интересно, как будет звучать это слово в творительном падеже множественного числа: второй вариант звучит немного более поэтично, и, если проводить аналогию, слово "люди" меняется так же. Но кажется, допустим и первый вариант.

*"Иди ебись со своими блядями" или "Иди ебись со своими блядьми"?*

Comment: надуманная проблема, обсуждать что-то на примере обсценной лексии без всяго повода

Comment: Согласен с  behemothus. Без правок перенесу «примеры» в конец текста, чтобы не светились на главной странице.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл небольшое исследование на эту тему в статье 2011 года лингвиста Владимира Ивановича Беликова [МЕТОДИЧЕСКИЕ НОВОСТИ В СОЦИАЛЬНОЙ ЛЕКСИКОГРАФИИ XXI ВЕКА](https://blogs.helsinki.fi/slavica-helsingiensia/files/2019/11/03-sh40.pdf):

> Вариативность тв. мн. у этого слова словарями не отмечается. Под
> «словарями», кроме БТС, я имею в виду Словарь русского языка XVIII
> века, где в ст. блядь («после 1730-х гг. в книгах как непристойное не
> употр.») форма тв. мн. также не упомянута. При аккуратно налаженном
> лексикографическом процессе, например, при наличии инструкции,
> требующей в оговоренных случаях обязательного заполнения определенных
> полей словарной статьи (правда, оговорить такие случаи должен
> профессиональный лингвист) , академическому словарю следовало бы
> верить. В этом случае «вера», вероятно, означала бы «ясно, что тв. мн.
> всегда блядями».
>
> Вообще-то бывает по-разному, и давно по-разному. У Пушкина – с одной
> стороны, Когда ж вновь сядем вчетвером С блядьми, вином и чубуками?, с
> другой – Он с блядями целый век, Он у них, как дома. У Полежаева в
> «Сашке» то так, то эдак: А как мой Сашка пировать С блядьми в трактире
> научился, Я и забыл вам рассказать и Теперь, какими же судьбами, Меня
> вы спросите опять, Сидит в трактире он с блядями?  В современной
> профессиональной литературе вариант блядьми встречается в два раза
> реже (в Журнальном зале 16 текстов против 32 ), в любительской – в три
> раза реже (в Самиздате 64 текста и 193 ), анализ блогосферы позволяет
> говорить о некоторых территориальных и возрастных различиях (Табл. 8).
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> Вариант блядьми явно вытесняется, но устаревшим его пока нельзя
> считать; для сравнения приведу статистику по вариантам дочерьми и
> дочерями, где соотношение частотностей варианта дочерьми в разных
> сегментах позволяет квалифицировать его как устаревающее и
> («разговорное»?) сниженное:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]